# When should you stop expanding the horizon of a CSP?

Tags: algorithm, constraints, artificial-intelligence, constraint-satisfaction

When should you stop expanding the horizon of a CSP planner?
 Specifically,is there a condition of a constraint-satisfaction problem planner that, when arc consistency with search fails at some horizon implies that arc consistency will also fail for all longer horizons.

Answer (score -1):

If your planner is very general the answer has to be no.

Suppose that your constraint system is general enough that it can check "Each row of this matrix corresponds to the tape of a Turing machine and row i is a snapshot of the state of the Turing machine after step i and the final row shows that the Turing machine has halted".

Then "I have found a Matrix satisfying the constraints" corresponds to "This Turing machine has halted" and by https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem pretty much the only way to find out if a Turing machine or other general computation has halted is to play thing out and wait to see if it halts.

Comment: Thanks for the different view of the problem, hadn't even considered using the halting problem.

Comment: Strips-planning is decidable, it's in PSPACE even. So the analogy to the halting problem fails.

Comment: I can see that if you are solving the constraints for a fixed area you can do this in PSPACE by trying all possible combinations. What I think the Turing machine analogy shows is that, for a solution to exist, the area may have to be unpredictably large.